# xcode crashed while rebuilding of project

Tags: xcode4, xcodebuild

My xcode have crashed giving following error whenever I try to run my already running project.

> Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of all unsaved data.

I have tried reopening my xcode, restarting mac, clearing total cache and finally reinstalling my sdk 4.3 version but I am still getting the error. Can some one advice me how can I get rid of this error.

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: This isn't programming related but rather an Xcode bug. Contact Apple Developer Technical Support and/or file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no option but to go back to previous version of the xcode. Now I am using xcode 3.2 and it is working great but I still miss the new features that were provided in xcode 4

Answer (score 1):

With me all standard tricks (cache-flush, preferences-purge) didn't help.

What DID help in the end was removing the 'xcuserdata' from the XCode project package. Apparently there were some corrupt user-dependent setting there.